# How to check if a page comes after clicking the back button using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, back

I have a form where I am calculating the total amount using jQuery.
The function I created for that is `updateTotal();`

and the form action is another page and the action page has this button:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="history.go(-1);" type="submit" name="edit">EDIT</button>
```

so when the user clicks on the EDIT button page goes back to the form again (first page) and all the filled up details are there except the repetitve fields created using jQuery.
The sample form is here in [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/riffaz/dx32dd4y/)

I just want to run this function `updateTotal();` if the user comes to the form by clicking the EDIT (basically browse go back) button..

Is there any way to do this in jQuery?

**UPDATES FOR FUTURE REFERENCE - I SOLVED IT LIKE THIS**

html:

```
<input type="text" id="amount" name="amount[]" placeholder="Amount" required="required" class="form-control inputChangeVal reqF reqFamount" data-js-input-type="number" />
```

and the jQuery :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var hiddenTot = jQuery('.reqFamount').val() ;
    jQuery(".totalAmount").val(hiddenTot);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a hidden field to store the computed value.

```
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenTotal" />
```

Then store the calculated value to the hidden field with Id 'hiddenTotal'.

```
function updateTotal() {
        var price = 0;

        $(".inputChangeVal").each(function() {
            var t = parseFloat(jQuery(this).val(), 10);
            price = price + t;
        });

        var total = price.toFixed(2);
        $(".totalAmount").val(total);
        $("#hiddenTotal").val(total);
    }
```

Then when the browse back is triggered the hiddenfield is automatically filled by the browser. 
Next check when the document is ready, read the value of hiddenTotal and write to totalAmount.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    // read value and set value of totalAmount to hiddentotal;
    var hiddenTotal = $("#hiddenTotal").val() || 0; //use the hiddenTotal value or if not present set 0 as the default value
    $(".totalAmount").val(hiddentotal)
}
```

Now totalAmount is restored. This even works when you leave the page and return using your browsers history.

Comment: this is not clear enough for everyone.. anyhow the idea worked... thanks

Comment: Explain in details. I m not getting